# Docker not running a command

Tags: node.js, docker

```
PS C:\E Drive\Docker\api> docker run --name myapp_c_nodemon -p 4000:4000 --rm -v C:\E Drive\Docker\api:/app -v /app/node_modules myapp:nodemon
docker: invalid reference format.
```

It's giving invalid reference format

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that ```rm``` command? If you can explain what you want your command to do, we might be able to help you further.

Comment: I think it removes containers

Comment: @DusayantaPrasad It's not a command, it's an option. And like OP says, it removes the container when it terminates.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in your host directory name, so you need to enclose it in quotes like this

```
docker run --name myapp_c_nodemon -p 4000:4000 --rm -v "C:\E Drive\Docker\api":/app -v /app/node_modules myapp:nodemon
```